# Error on double click on lightning:inputField lookup field

Tags: lookup, lightning-inputfield

I created a lightning:inputField which supposed to show the lookup field for customer. However, when I double click on the field or when I try to select the current entry I get an error message.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="contract" type="Contract__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contract__c' }" access="public"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" /> 
<div class="slds-clearfix slds-card forceDetailPanelDesktop inlineEditEnabled">             
    <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Contract__c">
         <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-3">
                <div class="slds-form-element slds-hint-parent slds-p-around--x-small hasDiv">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-has-divider--bottom" style="min-height: 18px;">
                          <lightning:inputField fieldName="Customer__c" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</div>
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Can you please share your code as well?

Comment: Can you please COPY and PASTE your piece of code that has the issue? Good thing here is, you could format it to have a good indentation as well.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Why us this question off-topic?

Comment: Not sure why others voted so. I kind of agree with you here, but since it's a [gack](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html) all we can do is tell you to contact support.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue (among others) so eventually I abandoned all hope and started to use the [strike lookup component](http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikeLookup) instead. It works much better although as mentioned in the following post the New Record option doesn't work properly: [lightning:inputField as lookup missing "New Record" option](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207538/lightninginputfield-as-lookup-missing-new-record-option?noredirect=1#comment313304_207538)

If you go with strike be advised that to continue using `lightning:recordEditForm` you will need to load the parent Id manually into the strike lookup field after form-load (handle the `onload` event) and also sync back any changes like this:

```
onFormLoad : function(component, event, helper) {
    // set contactId
    component.set('v.contactId', component.find('input_contactId').get('v.value'));
},

copyContactId : function(component, event, helper) {
    var contactId = component.get('v.contactId');
    component.find('input_contactId').set('v.value', contactId);
}
```

Component markup:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.contactId}" action="{!c.copyContactId}"/>

<lightning:recordEditForm onload="{!c.onFormLoad}" ...>
    <!-- Workaround to fix lookup component -->
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Contact__c" class="hidden" aura:id="input_contactId"/>
    <c:strike_lookup value="{!v.contactId}" .../>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another workaround. The idea is to prevent the event from being fired. I created a controller function and assigned this function to the lightning:inputField for the onmouseup-event. I still believe that this is a bug.

```
preventDefault: function(component, event, helper){
     event.preventDefault();       
 },

<lightning:inputField fieldName="Customer__c" onmouseup="{!c.preventDefault}" />
```