# lightning:inputField as lookup missing "New Record" option

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lookup, create-records, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

Is it just me or is the `lightning:inputField` component missing the "New Record" option when it's rendered as a lookup?

Right now I have to type a value in the lookup field, hit enter, and wait for the pop-up window to open before I can see the option to create a new record.

This is a major bummer because:

- either I have to use an external library such as Strike, which uses force:createRecord in its logic which is a problem of its own since a callback cannot be defined to prevent users from being redirected to the newly-created record page (i.e. doesn't work!),
- or I have to create my own component mimicking a New Record UI, which I can't see an easy way of doing.

Comment: I'm also having trouble with lookups - FYI [Anyone got a lightning:inputField working for a lookup?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207479/anyone-got-a-lightninginputfield-working-for-a-lookup).