# lightning:inputField lookup does not support new record creation?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

After implementing a simple lightning:inputField and utilizing lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="myObject__c" i was able to create lookup field in my form corresponding to one of the lookup field in myObject__c.

However i notice that unlike the other lookup field in normal Salesforce as well as force:inputField lookup, this lookup field does not have the capability to create new record.
[image]

Am i missing something here in the use of lightning:inputField?

Comment: I can see other [open questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207538/lightninginputfield-as-lookup-missing-new-record-option) on stack where there is no answer to it. Documentation is not clear either.

Comment: Wow, so does this mean we're basically scre#3d  other than building a component to do it ourselves? Because i thought at first that since Salesforce themselves have such functionality on the UI that surely there has to be a way for us to tap into the same functionality for the lightning component meant to do that job.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new record from the lookup field's dropdown menu is currently not supported. Check documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation

You need to create a custom lookup implementation. Example: https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc